# Riemann Integration and integrability of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Can anyone explain the need for Riemann integrability? From my limited knowledge of integration, the existence of $\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0}\sum_a^b f(x)\Delta x$, and its convergence suffices the integrability of a function. Here, I am considering integration from $a$ to $b$.

Does integrability of function refers to riemann integrability in general?

Comment: Integrability of $f$ and $f$ is integrable are same.

Comment: Ask where in an interval of size $\Delta x$ is the $x$ that you would use in $f(x)$ ? For continuous functions it makes no difference, but for others it does. Riemann is one way of dealing with that.